# difference between ejs templat(.ejs) and html templates(.tmplt)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

On web i was searching for templates i came across the html templates whose extension is .tmplt which can aslo be used for rendring data in html page using java script. Just got curious what is that, how is that different from .ejs and which one is better?

Answer (score 0):

After a brief google search, I couldn't find any documentation on anything related to `.tmplt` files. There's a good chance that whoever wrote that code in the `.tmplt` file just added that extension as his own style. File extensions don't really matter when it comes to templating, as you typically specify the full file-name when rendering it.

To answer your question, `.tmplt` is a made up extension by the original developer. The `.ejs` extension is meant to be used for [Effective Javascript Templating](http://ejs.co/). My suggestion would be to use the standard `.ejs` extension if it is a valid EJS file, even though neither is really 'better'.